# Writing a bat file to place a iexplorer icon on users desktop

Tags: batch-file, sharepoint

I want to place a bat file on my webserver and send the link to my users. The file will install an internet explorer shortcut to my sharepoint site. I have the ico file also on my web server. I can't get it to work, but here's what I got.

```
echo [InternetShortcut] > "%userprofile%\Desktop\Sharepoint.URL"
echo URL="C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplorer.exe" https://lpc.sharesrvr.com >> "%userprofile%\Desktop\Sharepoint.URL"
echo IconFile=www.leonardpaper.com/Images/Sharepoint.ico >> "%userprofile%\Desktop\Sharepoint.URL"
echo IconIndex=0 >> "%userprofile%\Desktop\Sharepoint.URL"
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>I think `URL` will not accept `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplorer.exe"` as `URL`, so if you remove it, it should work.</s>
Edit:
 This should work. The only thing that makes me think that it might not work , is having omitted "http"

```
(
echo [InternetShortcut]
echo URL=https://lpc.sharesrvr.com
echo IconFile=http://www.leonardpaper.com/Images/Sharepoint.ico
echo IconIndex=0
)>"%userprofile%\Desktop\Sharepoint.URL"
```

Also iexplore.exe instead of iexplore**r**.exe

Comment: What about putting all these `echo`s in parenthesis and redirecting the entire code block once only?